# How to change spreadsheet theme also change HTML style and background

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

My idea is - which that we can always change theme in the spreadsheet, and the HTML sidebar style also change after re-open the sidebar depends on spreadsheet theme

First - I get color and font style from my spreadsheet theme. I might get the incorrect value, but this the idea I've come so far

```
function getFont() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSpreadsheetTheme().getFontFamily()
}

function getBG() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSpreadsheetTheme().getThemeColors()[0].BACKGROUND
}

function getTextColor() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSpreadsheetTheme().getThemeColors()[0].TEXT
}
```

Then I want to paste those color and font style on HTML to change the style. I'm very new for HTML so I've come with this

```
<style>

  body {
    background-color: <?= getBG() ?>;
    font: <?= getFont() ?>;
    color: <?= getTextColor() ?>;
  }

</style>
```

or any better solutions to do this I would like to hear more

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try converting it into hex:  Something like `getSpreadsheetTheme().getConcreteColor("TEXT").asRgbColor().getHexCode()`

Comment: @TheMaster Thanks, I tried and it works I now got the color as I wanted. But I'll make some small changes because it's error when I run `...getConcreteColor(SpreadsheetApp.ThemeColorType.TEXT).asRgbColor().asHexString()`

Comment: Great. I added a answer

Comment: I see you edited your question to a new issue. Which I don't understand. Consider asking a separate question.

Comment: The font doesn't work yet, it should be Verdana font. But as I see my HTML, it still be plain texts

Comment: What is the font logged?

Comment: it's logged just Verdana, i'm thinking of `font:` in HTML style might be incorrect?

Comment: Wait, it somehow works just put `-family` after `font` in HTML style. Let add this to your answer too. I actually first time do style for HTML, and your advice got me thinking possible ways, thank you

Comment: I just realized I should revise my question to be unsolved so it would not be confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get accurate color, get hex color string by using [getConcreteColor()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-theme#getconcretecolorthemecolortype):

```
SpreadsheetApp
 .getActive()
 .getSpreadsheetTheme()
 .getConcreteColor(
    SpreadsheetApp.ThemeColorType.TEXT
 )
 .asRgbColor()
 .asHexString()
```

---

The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font) for font states

> If font is specified as a shorthand for several font-related properties, then:
>
> it must include values for:
>
> > font-size
> > font-family

```
font : 1em <?= getFont() ?>;
```

Alternatively, you can just use `font-family`.